# Why my following question was closed?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/46348/23084) question of mine has been closed. Can I know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the reason for closure by clinking on the link you provided: [What is an art? When an act becomes an art? what is it's length & breadth?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/46348/what-is-an-art-when-an-act-becomes-an-art-what-is-its-length-breadth)

It was believed by those voting to close as "off-topic".

Here are more details: "While this question may be related to philosophy or occur in a philosophical context, the question itself doesn't seem to be about philosophy, and is therefore not a good fit for our site."

If you want to pursue this, you might edit the question and try to get it reopened or write a new question.